# Android - Main menu for simple app

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm making a simple android app, and I'm trying to work out the best way to make the main menu. The users of this app are not likely to be that sophisticated, so I want to make it as simple as possible.

So I want the first screen they see when the app opens to be this menu - they click on what they want, and it takes them to that part of the app (Not pressing a "Menu" button to bring it across from the left, which is common nowdays).

So, I want the menu to look a bit like this: http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/AppZapp-Android-Menu.jpg , minus the search box, and the strip down the right hand side. (also this looks like it is one of those menus that slide out from the left, which I dont want)

I have had a look into menus (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), but it seems it is more used for contextual stuff, or letting the user select an option), then a navigation menu.

So - what is the best way to do this? Do I just create a list and put a button in each item?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your requirement , Use Navigation drawer see the below link.

[Navigation drawer tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) 
[NavigationDrawerSample](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

After used navigation drawer, you need to add search view on navigation header.For more info see the link
 [SearchView tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks - but this menu slides out from the left, which isnt what I want at this point. I provided that example just as an example, but didnt want it sliding out from the left like that. I'm leaning towards using a listview (or something like that) for my menu.